# How to declare object with optional keys?

Tags: typescript

This code won't compile:

```
interface A {
  [key: string]?: string
}
```

While this does:

```
type Partial<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]?: T[P]
}
```

Why, and how to fix the first one?

P.S.

As a solution it's possible to use `Partial` but it doesn't look very nice:

```
type A = Partial<{
  [key: string]: string
}>
```

Comment: Do you want to allow **any** string key? If so it is just `interface A { [key: string]: string }`

Comment: Do you know ahead of time which keys you would like to make optional? Or, as @AlekseyL.asks, are you wanting to make any string key optional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types) all the keys are optional by default because you're specifying only key's type (`string` | `number`) and its value type, not the actual required key. So you don't need to add `?`.

```
interface A {
  [key: string]: string
}
```

Same with [type alias](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-aliases):

```
type A1 = {
  [key: string]: string
}
```

Or [Record utility](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkt) (same as type alias):

```
type A2 = Record<string, string>;
```

---

`type Partial<T> = { [P in keyof T]?: T[P] }` is a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types). It creates new type based on another type and as in this example can make properties optional. By the way `Partial` is included in typescript utility types, no need to redeclare it.